# How do I raycast mouse positions for the last 0.25 seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, raycasting

I would like to raycast for the last 0.25 seconds of mouse movement.

Anything older than 0.25 seconds of movement should be removed from my queue.

Currently, I use a queue that is a max size (size). When it exceeds the max size it starts to remove entries. How do I convert this method to drop entries older than 0.25f seconds instead?

```
    //Ray Cache
    public Queue<Ray> inputRays;
    int counter = 0;
    int size = 10;//size of queue

/**********************************************/

private void Start()
{
    inputRays = new Queue<Ray>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    QueueInputRays();
}


  private void QueueInputRays()
    {
        if (counter < size)
        {
            inputRays.Enqueue(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition));
            counter += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            inputRays.Enqueue(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition));
            inputRays.Dequeue();
        }
    }
```

Comment: one way to try to solve this is not using Rays directly, but using a new class which will contain a Ray and the time when the Ray was casted. Then, look at the instance in the front of the queue and compare that time with the time now, so if the time is bigger than 0.25 you dequeue that instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to use the FixedUpdate then you can simply add to the queue for a certain amount. Enqueue until a certain count, then dequeue and enqueue.

If you know that 0.02 is the delta time for instance, then you need

```
0.25 / 0.02 = 12.5
```

round it to 12 and :

```
private Queue<Ray>queue = new Queue<Ray>();
public void AddToQueue(Ray ray)
{
   if(this.queue.Count > 12){ this.queue.Dequeue(); }
   this.queue.Enqueue(ray);
}
public Ray[] GetRays()
{ 
    return this.queue.ToArray();
}
```

This will make things more simple coz you don't have to keep track of timer. That is if FixedUpdate is able to run as defined speed.